# Detect when interial scrolling begins WinRT XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Someone I've been banging my head around - is there a way to detect when intertial scrolling begins on a scrollviewer in WinRT's XAML model in a touch input scerario, no matter how round abouts it is?

I've tried listening to PointerUp & Down's & Released & Move events on UI elements and on the CoreWindow object itself and none of them fire after the scrollviewer starts moving (so it seems the scrollviewer is eating the pointer moved events before the application Window even recieves them? What fun DirectInput is...)? And of course overlaying something on top the of scrollviewer that catches events and then says it hasn't handled them simply doesn't work (I'm guessing a side effect of DirectInput again). So is there a way to do, without writing my own panel?

(I've been tasked to write a flipview like control where the items scale / zoom up as they become the active item - and it looks horrible to only fire it on the selection changed event).

Comment: afaik you can access the scroll viewer of controls which should provide the events

Comment: I can get the scrollviewer, and it's scrollbars - but the scrollviewer is a special instance where it doesn't fire and input or manipulation events for you to use because they're all handled by the higher performance DirectInput APi, rather than whatever else is handling XAML input events for everything else